# Copy hive table to mysql using sqoop -- Time Format Exception

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to copy hive table to mysql table.

Hive table

id, name, joined_at

```
1, john, 2013-04-04 10:10:10
2, jane, 2013-05-05 11:11:11
```

Here Id is Int, name is string and joined_at is string.

I am trying to copy this table to mysql table with schema `id (int)`, `name(nvarchar)` and `joined_at (datetime)`.

My sqoop command is as follows

```
sqoop export --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://mysqlserver/databasename" --username myuser --password mypassword --table mysqltable --columns "id,name,joined_at" --export-dir /hive/warehouse/myhivetable --input-fields-terminated-by " "
```

Here I receive the error with time format must be `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.ffffff]`. I am not able to understand were I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is with fields terminator/separator character. Try below suggestions might work for you

while creating hive table specify character which terminates fields e.g in hive create table query 
    `DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ESCAPED BY '\\'`

And specify same charater in sqoop export e.g in sqoop export
    `--input-fields-terminated-by '\t' --lines-terminated-by '\n' --input-null-string "\\\\N"  --input-null-non-string "\\\\N"`